# android firebase admin sdk error 'All firebase libraries must be either above or below 14.0.0'

Tags: android, firebase, sdk, admin

Can anybody help me to solve this problem?
I want to use firebase-admin for my project, but when I want to sync the build.gradle the error says: All firebase libraries must be either above or below 14.0.0.

> Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: All firebase libraries must be either above or below 14.0.0

and my depedencies are:

```
...
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:15.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:15.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:15.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:5.11.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.0'
...
```

I tried to change the firebase version to lower than 14 but the problem stays the same.
Only when I comment 'implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:5.11.0'' Gradle can sync the project.

Thanks,
Rama

Comment: firebase-admin should be used server side, do you really want to include it in the android app?

Comment: I want to have an admin that can add/edit/delete other user.
Is there any other way to do that besides adding firebase-admin?
Thanks

Comment: Using admin operations android side is really really dangerous, avoid that. Use your server app to perform this kind of operations

Comment: Thanks for the warning. So you are suggesting have separate app to do the user admin? Thanks

Comment: Setup your server app