# Firebase Admin in backend module triggers "All firebase libraries must be either above or below 14.0.0

Tags: firebase, android-studio, gradle, google-cloud-endpoints, firebase-admin

I have an android studio project that includes one module for my app and one module for my backend.

According to the documentation I can use the following code to bring all the build endpoint libraries to my app module:

```
endpointsServer project(path: ':backend', configuration: 'endpoints')
```

In my backend module gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.cloud.tools:endpoints-framework-gradle-plugin:1.0.3'
        classpath 'com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-gradle-plugin:1.3.5'
    }

}

repositories {
    jcenter(); }

apply plugin: 'java' apply plugin: 'war'

apply plugin: 'com.google.cloud.tools.appengine'
apply plugin: 'com.google.cloud.tools.endpoints-framework-server'

sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.endpoints:endpoints-framework:2.0.14'
    implementation 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5'
    implementation 'javax.inject:javax.inject:1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:5.11.0'
}

appengine {
    deploy {
        stopPreviousVersion = false
        promote = false
        version = '1'
        project = 'project-name'
    } }
```

In my app module gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.cloud.tools.endpoints-framework-client'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
        classpath 'com.google.cloud.tools:endpoints-framework-gradle-plugin:1.0.2'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "appID"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1"
        multiDexEnabled = true
        resConfigs "en", "fr"
    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
        preDexLibraries = false
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            zipAlignEnabled true
            debuggable false
        }
        debug {
            signingConfig null
        }
    }

}

repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

dependencies {
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.2@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }

    implementation('com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.3.1')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.2'
    endpointsServer project(path: ':backend', configuration: 'endpoints')

    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.23.0'
    implementation 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-android:1.23.0'
    implementation 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-gson:1.23.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:15.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:15.1.0'
    implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-jobdispatcher-with-gcm-dep:0.8.5'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

configurations {
    all {
        exclude module: 'httpclient'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

The problem is that when gradle is executing is causing the following error:

> All firebase libraries must be either above or below 14.0.0

I have already looked at:

[How to add firebase-admin to my android project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47581505/how-to-add-firebase-admin-to-my-android-project)
and
[android firebase admin sdk error 'All firebase libraries must be either above or below 14.0.0' [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50116819/android-firebase-admin-sdk-error-all-firebase-libraries-must-be-either-above-or)

But both of them are trying to add the admin sdk on client side. Which is not why I am trying to do.

So how can I tell gradle that this are two different modules or how can I exclude the admin sdk from coming to my app module when I am using:

```
endpointsServer project(path: ':backend', configuration: 'endpoints')
```

Comment: The only way I have found for now is to remove the `endpointsServer project(path: ':backend', configuration: 'endpoints')` and import all the clientLibs manually in my app project as jars, but this is quite inefficient :(

Comment: Please edit your question to show your entire, minimal build.gradle files for both modules.

Comment: I have edited the code. Thanks!

Comment: I don't know enough about this Google Cloud Endpoints product to know what it's doing to your build.  Try running `./gradlew :app:dependencies` to figure out what is pulling in an offending library in your build.

Comment: Also, where is your buildscript classpath for com.google.gms:google-services?  Seems like you'd need that in order to use the google-services plugin, which is the thing generating the message.

Comment: It is actually on the project gradle as instructed by google and it in dependencies. So `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.3.0'`

I have already tried the ./gradlew :app:dependencies but no luck. Not an expert on that to be honest but it does not seem to have any dependency on a firebase library below 14. I think the problem is the fact that the firebase-admin version is much lower (5.11.0) but that should have nothing to do with it as it is in another module...

Comment: What do you mean "no luck" with ./gradlew dependencies?  It should tell you exactly everything that's being pulled into your app.  Search it for a Firebase dependency that might be causing the message.  Then track where it came from.

Comment: So when I run the :yollty:dependencies I do not see in any of the pulled Firebase dependency that is below 15. The only one that I can see (which seems to causes the problem, as when removed it compiles) is this one: `endpointsServer - endpointsServer project(path: ':xyz', configuration: 'endpoints')
\--- project :backend` but this actually is suppose to bring only the compiled api libs and not the Firebase-Admin module.

As I mentioned in the initial comment when I remove this item and I add the compiled api libs manually to my libs folder then everything works correctly. Which isn't ideal